# is there iOS maps app in which i can download full city map?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps

i want to use some maps app on my iPhone without using internet connection. So is there iOS maps app in which i can download full city map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nokia maps are available for ios and other devices.
 http://m.here.com 
You may download and use them offline, for free, afaik.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the app [CityMaps2Go](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/city-maps-2go/id327783342?mt=8)

Comment: nice, but it is not free

Comment: Not all things in life are. Plus your question didn't specify that as a requirement.